# Bootstrap Container Use In Relation To Website Layout

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I’m a little confused on how to use Bootstrap’s containers. Am I supposed to nest the entire body of the webpage within a single container and then use rows for each section of the webpage? Or do I use individual containers for each section of my webpage?

For example, this...

```
<body>
  <div class ="container-fluid">
    <nav>Nav bar code</nav>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-*-*" > body stuff </div>
      <div class="col-*-*" > body stuff </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-*-*" > more body stuff </div>
      <div class="col-*-*" > more  body stuff </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

...or this?

```
<body>
  <div class ="container-fluid">
    <nav>Nav bar code</nav>
  </div>
  <div class ="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-*-*" > body stuff </div>
      <div class="col-*-*" > body stuff </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class ="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-*-*" > more body stuff  </div>
      <div class="col-*-*" > more  body stuff </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Whichever does what you need it to do...

Comment: Is there an advantage or disadvantage to one method over the other?

Comment: Nope. You can even nest containers inside of rows, but funky stuff starts happening with your margins if you go too crazy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both, it depends on your need.  You are able to use as many as the container you want. For example, if you want to have different sections with the different background color you can use multiple containers. If you want to have different image background you can use multiple containers as well.